# password_verify always invalid password although password is correct

Tags: php, mysql, hashcode, bcrypt

I don't have idea what is the trouble in my code 
hash.php(insert bycryp password)

```
**<?php
$con = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "hast") or die(mysqli_error());
if (array_key_exists("f5", $_GET)) {
    $w5 = $_GET['f5'];//pass
}
if (array_key_exists("f6", $_GET)) {
    $w6 = $_GET['f6'];//pass
}
$salt = md5(uniqid(rand()));
$options = [
  'cost' =>11,
  'salt' => $salt
];
$hash_password = password_hash($w6, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options)."\n";
 $sql = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO `pass`(`nama`, `hash_password`, `salt`) VALUES ('$w5','$hash_password','$salt')")or die(mysqli_error($con));
    if ($sql) {
        echo $hash_password;
    } else {
        echo "gagal";
    }
?>**
```

hashlog.php

```
**<?php
$con = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "hast") or die(mysqli_error());
if (array_key_exists("f5", $_GET)) {
    $w5 = $_GET['f5'];//user
}
if (array_key_exists("f6", $_GET)) {
    $w6 = $_GET['f6'];//pass
}
$sql = mysqli_query($con, "select hash_password from pass where nama='$w5'")or die(mysqli_error($con));
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
$hash = $row['hash_password'];
$hash = $row['hash_password'];
//$hash ='$2y$11$0be5c43957cd3df608521u4PiYrUUyK/dQRSlc/g5UVdDdKk1WChy';
if (password_verify($w6, $hash)) {
    echo 'Password is valid!';
} else {
    echo 'Invalid password.';
}
?>**
```

in my case always invalid password although password is correct
please help me

Comment: Providing the salt option in PHP 7.0 will generate a deprecation warning. Support for providing a salt manually may be removed in a future PHP release. [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) will create a secure salt automatically for you if you do not specify one.

Comment: for debuggin porpouses, call `password_verify($w6, $hash)` after `password_hash` and let me know; also, check that the hashed password is the same with the one that is fetched from the DB

Comment: i call password_verify($w6, $hash) after password_hash stil invalid password, and password in DB is same with the one that is fetched @ConstantinGALBENU

Comment: Then, try to loose the `salt`, don't specify it, leave the library generate one and try again. password_verify should succeed if called immediately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you specify an invalid `salt` value. You should not specify the `salt` yourself, just leave the library generate one for you. If you really want to specify a `salt`, the use a code like this to do it:

```
$salt = mcrypt_create_iv(22, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);
```

**Also, I think that your problem is an appended `\n` at the hashed password; you must remove it:**

```
$hash_password = password_hash($w6, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options)."\n"; //remove this "\n"
```

Comment: it still have same problem invalid password when i change $salt

Comment: @RizkaNugroho take a look at this code: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/36c2b9d9650d96663320933bba4819bcf1376713